# Value of NSString returns null, but unsure why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I've set the value of my NSString called "fid" to responseObject (see below). responseObject returns the data I want when NSLog'd, but for some reason when I NSLog fid further down, it's empty. Am I missing something? See code:

**.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *fid;
```

**.m**

```
[DIOSFile fileSave:file success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"File uploaded!");

    [file setObject:[responseObject objectForKey:@"fid"] forKey:@"fid"];
    [file removeObjectForKey:@"file"];

 fid = [responseObject objectForKey:@"fid"];
        NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);

 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Failed to upload file!");
  }];

    NSDictionary *bodyValues = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:_itemDescrip.text, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value", nil]];
    NSDictionary *languageDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:bodyValues] forKey:@"und"];
    [nodeData setObject:languageDict forKey:@"body"];

    [nodeData setObject:@"storage_item" forKey:@"type"];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [dict setObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fid] forKey:@"fid"];
    NSLog(@"%@", fid);

    NSDictionary *fidLangDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:dict] forKey:@"und"];

    [nodeData setObject:fidLangDict forKey:@"field_photo"];

    [DIOSNode nodeSave:nodeData success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Node saved!");


    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Node did not save!");
    }];
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the DIOSFile class but if the lifetime of that responseObject is shorter than the lifetime of the fid property, you'll end up with a zombie (pointer to unallocated space) on your hands. I would change assign to strong in fid and do [[responseObject objectForKey:@"fid"] copy].

Comment: FYI - it's dangerous to use `assign` for an object pointer property. Assuming you are using ARC, use `strong`. Or if you really have a good reason and fully understand the consequences, use `weak`. `assign` should only be used for primitive types.

Comment: @JoelMurphy Tried it; no dice :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSString value returning before Block has run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926504/nsstring-value-returning-before-block-has-run)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling an asynchronous method.

The log statement "further down" is executed long before the fileSave method is completed. The two callbacks of fileSave will be called sometime in the distant future (could be many seconds from now).

Whatever you want to do that needs fid must be done in the completion block of fileSave.

Comment: Is there no way to grab what's in responseObject and use it outside of the fileSave method?

Comment: Add a method to your class called -saveSuccess and call it from within the success block. Add the NSLog there and see if it works.

Comment: @JoelMurphy & gnasher729: I need to be able to use the value of responseObject outside of the method in order for this line to work: [nodeData setObject:fidLangDict forKey:@"field_photo"]; That line doesn't set the field if it's located inside of the fileSave block.

Comment: @brittany: The next thing I'd recommend is changing all of your fid references to self.fid.